# jquery form submission canceled

Tags: javascript, jquery

am using dynamic form submission using jquery when form is submitted the error shown

"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

```
$('<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/almadar/appointment-form">
 <input type="hidden" name="dept" value="'+dept+'">
 <input type="hidden" name="doctor" value="'+doctor+'">
 <input type="hidden" name="hours" value="'+hours+'">'
).submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the form in the dom, then submit:

```
var $form = $('<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/almadar/appointment-form"><input type="hidden" name="dept" value="'+dept+'"><input type="hidden" name="doctor" value="'+doctor+'"><input type="hidden" name="hours" value="'+hours+'">')
.appendTo('body')

$form.submit()
```